# jQuery builds incorrect DOM from HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I found out jQuery does not always create the correct DOM from an HTML string. Here is a little example code:

```
var x = "<div><p><ul><li>1</li></ul></p></div>";
console.log('x = ' + x);
console.log('jQuery(x) = ' + jQuery(x).html());
var y = "<div><div><ul><li>1</li></ul></div></div>";
console.log('y = ' + y);
console.log('jQuery(y) = ' + jQuery(y).html());
```

Here is the output I get running this with jQuery 1.7.1:

```
x = <div><p><ul><li>1</li></ul></p></div>
jQuery(x) = <p></p><ul><li>1</li></ul><p></p>
y = <div><div><ul><li>1</li></ul></div></div>
jQuery(y) = <div><ul><li>1</li></ul></div>
```

As you can see, the second example creates the correct DOM, the first example does not. The only difference is a `<p>` tag instead of a `<div>`. Is this a bug or feature of jQuery?

Comment: You are specifying invalid html. It is the input that is incorrect not the output. The html you see in the result is auto-corrected html.

Comment: @downvoter: Seriously?  It's a good question.  Upvoting to counteract.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's *probably* a browser nuance, [since `<ul>` elements are illegal in `<p>` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5681514/304588).

What's probably happening is that, when jQuery attempts to create the HTML elements in your string as it understood it, the browser is "auto-correcting" the HTML generated as jQuery goes along.

Comment: Yepper, this is most likely it.

Comment: Thats it, try it directly; `document.body.innerHTML = x; alert (document.body.innerHTML)`