# Strange html error with paragraph

Tags: html

So i have this code:

```
<p id="item_1">
    <div class="background displayInline deleteItemFromCart" title="Delete item"></div>
    some text
</p>
```

Simple right? now what would happen if i would view the source in `Chrome` dev tools:

[image]

And as you can see for some reason `<p>` doesn't contain anything any more.

If i would try to remove div text would be back in `<p>` tag again, so my best guess would be that `<p>` can't contain any or just div elements?

**EDIT** Well it was stupid question, anyways now that i think about it i could have just used `<ul>` instead of `<p>` if i was going to build a list of things... Anyways thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, `<p>` can just contain inline elements and text, but `<div>` is a block element.

The inline elements are: `a` `abbr` `acronym` `applet` `b` `basefont` `bdo` `big` `br` `button` `cite` `code` `del` `dfn` `em` `font` `i` `img` `ins` `input` `iframe` `kbd` `label` `map` `object` `q` `samp` `script` `select` `small` `span` `strong` `sub` `sup` `textarea` `tt` `var`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't strange. It's simply wrong markup :)

```
<p id="item_1">
    <span style="display:block" class="background displayInline deleteItemFromCart" title="Delete item"></span>
    some text
</p>
```

But while inline styles are bad you should put something like this to your master.css file.

```
p span {display:block}
// Or
#item_1 span {display:block}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `p` tag **cannot** contain block-level elements, including itself.  Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

Answer (score 1):

P can only contain inline element.

See this link for a quick discussion on inline element/flow content.

[Should ol/ul be inside <p> or outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside)