# Validation: end tag for element "P" which is not open

Tags: html, w3c

The Following Code i wrote will not pass the W3C validator, instead it will give me the following Error:

> Line 18, Column 7: end tag for element "P" which is not open

Its the closing `</p>` tag imediately after the `</ul>` tag. And im realy having trouble to nail the problem down. Here is the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html lang="de">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>foo</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="foo1">
        <div class="foo2">
            <h1>some heading</h1>
                <p>
                    <ul>
                    <li>some stuff</li>
                    <li>yet another stuff</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
                <p>yet another heading</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ul not allowed in `<p>` Tag in Html 4. better try like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html lang="de">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>foo</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="foo1">
        <div class="foo2">
            <h1>some heading</h1>

                    <ul>
                    <li>some stuff</li>
                    <li>yet another stuff</li>
                    </ul>

                <p>yet another heading</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside)

In HTML4 it's invalid to put `ul` inside `p`.

Answer (score 1):

The W3C Validator does not allow you to put `<ul>` inside `<p></p>` for HTML 4.01 Strict. It also doesn't require the `</p>`.

So you can solve your problem by removing the `</p>` or removing both `<p>` and `</p>`.