# jQuery slidetoggle being glitchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

To start this off I will describe where I started. I first had a set up like this:

```
<div class="Q">
    <p><strong>What is an exchange?</strong></p>
    <p class="A">Text goes in here</p>
</div>
```

This was working okay in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/p4XJY/5/) but I have a few answers that contain a `ul` or `table` with information in it. The `p` would hide just fine but it would not hide the `ul` or `table`.

As I was writing this answer I decided to make the `p class="A"` into a `span` which now hides them but caused an even weirder problem. When you click on the question it will instantly display the content. Then when you click on it once again it will scroll like it should but does some weird fading glitch at the end.

Before I made it into a span it scrolled up and down just fine but it would slowly glitch at the end of scrolling it up.

The first 8 questions are currently set up as `spans` so you can see the odd effect I am getting. The questions after that show how the glitch happens when they are set as a `p`.

Here is the live site, [click here.](http://healthbenefitsohio.com/resources.php)

**HTML**

```
<div class="Q">
    <p><strong>What is an exchange?</strong></p>
    <span class="A">Answer goes here</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Q and A Format */

.Q > p > strong {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.A {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.Q ').on('click', function() { // Q and A function
    $(this).find('.A').stop(true).slideToggle(500);
});
```

I have used this function numerous times and I am a little puzzled by how it is behaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glitch is 2-fold.

The styling of the `<span>` that is being toggled is set as `display: inline` when visible. Instead of a `<span>` use a `<p>` and that should fix your issue. (The default display property of a `<span>` is inline as opposed to a `<p>` which is block.)

Secondly, the `<p>` that the header text is in should have `margin: 0`.

Comment: Hmm you have a good eye, I didn't see it adding inline. I have one problem though, I can't use a `p` because it won't hide the `ul`, `ol`, or `table` I have inside of them. I originally had it as a `p` tag and it still works but that was my original problem of the glitch with a `p` tag.

Comment: Alright the `margin: 0;` cleared up the slight glitch with a `p` tag but any idea on why the `p` tag won't hide any of the `ul`, `ol`, or `table`?

Comment: If the toggle element won't work with a `p` tag try a `div` instead. A `div` also has a default display value of block.

Comment: I appreciate all of the help with this but after trying a few more options they are all glitching out. I think I am just going to scrap the idea and start another approach.

Comment: The issue with the `table, ul, ol` would be that they would have to be a child (inside) of the parent `p` or `div` tag as opposed to being adjacent (next to). I think your approach was OK, just needed some fine tuning.

Comment: I figured out why the `p` was causing problems. Block elements like `ul` are not allowed inside of a `p` tag. I then decided to rewrite how I have the structure set up and here is the fiddle which seems to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/c8YbX/2/ This is the question I found out about `p` tags and `ul` tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside

Comment: Ah that makes sense too, didn't keep that into consideration. Cool, glad you got a working solution

Comment: Thank you for all the help and I am glad I got it working as well but now I need to convert 3 massive amounts of text into this format, yay me. :/