# ng-repeat inside UL (which is inside a P) is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**UPDATE**: *It seems Angular.js doesn't like the <ul> inside a <p>. So, as helpful commenters said, replacing the <p> with a <div> solves the problem.*

Sorry if this may be a newbie question on Angular.js but I just can't seem to find the error in this code. Consider the following HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="BlocksCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="block in blocks">
        <div id="{{block.id}}" class="{{block.classes}}">
            <div>
                <h1>{{block.title}}, {{block.dates}}
                    <br/>
                    <small>
                        <a href="{{block.place.link}}" target="_blank">
                            {{block.place.title}}</a>
                        ({{block.place.city_country}})
                    </small>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p><i class="{{block.icon_classes}}"></i></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        {{block.description.text}}
                    </p>
                    <p ng-repeat="item in block.description.items">
                        <b>{{item.title}}</b>: {{item.points.length}} - {{item.points[2].text}}
                        <ul class="fa-ul">
                            <li>
                                <i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>{{item.points[2].text}}
                            </li>
                            <li ng-repeat="point in item.points">
                                <i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>{{point.text}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript bit:

```
function BlocksCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.blocks = [
    {
      id: 'my-id',
      classes: 'class1 class2',
      title: 'This is the title',
      dates: '2007 / 2011',
      place: {
        link: 'http://www.example.com/',
        title: 'This is the place',
        city_country: 'City, Country'
      },
      icon_classes: 'fa fa-terminal fa-5x',
      description: {
        text: 'description test',
        items: [
          {
            title: 'Title test',
            points: [
              {text: 'item test 1'},
              {text: 'item test 2'},
              {text: 'item test 3'},
              {text: 'item test 4'}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ];
}
```

This will display the following output (you can check a working example on JSFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/uskL6/):

## This is the title, 2007 / 2011

### This is the place (City, Country)

description test

**Title test**: 4 - item test 3

Now can someone tell me how is it that the "{{item.points.length}} - {{item.points[2].text}}" bit works fine but the "{{item.points[2].text}}" and the ng-repeat inside the UL don't?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were using `<ol>` tag inside `<p>` tag. According to [Html documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) 
**List elements (in particular, ol and ul elements) cannot be children of p elements**.

So change `<p ng-repeat="">` to `<div ng-repeat="">` or `<span ng-repeat="">`

See this question in stack overflow **[Should ol/ul be inside `<p>` or outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside)**

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought it was simple...

Then it drove me crazy...

*The solution:* Change the `<p ng-repeat="...">` to `<div ng-repeat="...">`. Then it works; why, I do not know...

Comment: Seconded. Started working with the fiddle, simply replacing the paragraph with a div element made it all work.

Comment: Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I'm thinking it's Angular playing by the rules, us trying to break them. 

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1 specifically says that a Paragraph element cannot contain block level elements. UL being such an element, I think that is why stuff started breaking. 

Try going with an inline-element ng-repeat inside the paragraph (span, a, sub, object, button, input) and it should work.

**Confirmed**, using any inline element inside the <p> tag will allow the repeat through. Block level elements, no-go.

Comment: Yes, this could be it. But with browsers being so lenient usually, I wouldn't expect it.

Comment: Thanks, that does solve it. But it does seem a bit picky of Angular.js to follow those rules, considering that not even browsers have a problem with having a <ul> inside a <p>. Oh well, back to work. Thanks a lot, guys.