# Chrome and Firefox repair my Html tag?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following .html

```
<p>
    <input class="inputName" />
    <ul>
         <li>One value</li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

In google chrome, firefox and safari i got (in the source explorer)

```
<p>
    <input class="inputName" />
</p>
<ul>
     <li>One value</li>
</ul>
```

I can't reproduce the issue, it come from my smarty template .... somewhere but i have no idea where.

I don't know where to look. Every tags are closed. Have you ever seen that problem ?

Comment: You can´t write ul element into p!

**http://stackoverflow.com/a/5681796/1623198**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `<p>` tag cannot contain other block elements.  You most-likely want to use `<div>` instead of `<p>`:

```
<div>
    <input class="inputName" />
    <ul>
         <li>One value</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and Firefox are modifying the DOM in an attempt to comply with HTML standards, as [**`ul`/`ol` elements can't reside within a `p` node.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5681796/269970)

`p` cannot contain block-level elements (`div`, `ul`, `ol`), only inline elements (`span`).