# Why can't I hide my 'ul' with CSS like this?

Tags: html, css

I've used a ul in a paragraph tag and used CSS to hide it, but it won't work. How can I fix it?

Here's my HTML content:

```
<p id="transport">
    <img class="draco" src="../image/draco.png"/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="">c</a></li>
        <li><a href="">d</a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

And here is my CSS content:

```
p#transport ul {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    display: none;
}

p#transport:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is because you can't have an `ul` inside a `p` tag. The browser will adjust it for you.

Comment: i've change it to div and it works! THKS!

Comment: It should. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/6a0awqgv/embedded/result/ and check in your console where the HTML ends up. The browser will place the `ul` outside the `p`.

Comment: [The short answer is that ul elements are not legally allowed inside `p' elements.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside#answer-5681796)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you cannot put a `ul` inside a `p`. The browser interprets it as if you have forgotten to close the `p` tag and closes it itself. That is the reason the CSS rules do not apply.

Change the `p` tag to a `div` and it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you can't have an `ul` inside a `p` tag. Most browsers will change the HTML for you: place the `ul` outside the `p` tag. This is what it well may end up looking like:

```
<p id="transport">
    <img class="draco" src="../image/draco.png">
</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="">d</a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
<p></p>
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/6a0awqgv/embedded/result/. Compare the source code with the element inspector in your console.

So to overcome it you could do:

```
p#transport + ul {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    display: none;
}

p#transport:hover + ul{
    display: block;
}
```

The `+` is the [adjacent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Comment: Now I've got it, thks!