# ul breaks out of p elemant

Tags: html, html-lists

This really freaky thing has been happening. I have a code:

```
    <p class="desc"><img class="portrait" src="../images/albums/pxal_prism.jpg" />
     <ul class="song_list">

      <li>Prism</li>
      <li>Other Song</li>
      <li>Some other song</li>
      <li>you know...</li>
      <li>getting ridiculous</li>

    </ul>

   </p>
```

And when I do inspect element it appears like this:

```
    <p class="desc"><img class="portrait" src="../images/albums/pxal_prism.jpg" /></p>
     <ul class="song_list">

      <li>Prism</li>
      <li>Other Song</li>
      <li>Some other song</li>
      <li>you know...</li>
      <li>getting ridiculous</li>

    </ul>

   <p></p>
```

Because of this my ul is not at the right position (beside the pic). Please help.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside

Answer (score 1):

`<p>` expects inline content, but you specified a `<ul>` tag which is a block element. It is not allowed there, so the browser closes the `<p>` element automatically before the start of `<ul>`.

Think about the semantics for a second: `<p>` is called a *paragraph*. A paragraph can not contain lists. Instead of a paragraph, you should use a `<diV>` which expects *flow content*, so the `<ul>` tag is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1, **P** element "cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)."

`<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->`

It means **P** element can only have the inline elements inside it.

As per your html, you are using:

`<p>   --block element
  <img..../>   -- inline element which is allowed
  **<ul>...</ul>** -- block element which is not allowed
 </p>`

Instead of P you can use the **div** element.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `p` tag, you can use `div` tag.
Use CSS property (float: left) to `img` tag and `ul` so they will come beside each other.

Comment: You should really explain to the asker why you need to use a div instead. See this answer to the duplicate for more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside