# Javascript two dimensional arrays giving undefined before printing other arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Why I am getting undefined printed before list items. Don't where I am making mistake. Please help me out. Please consider the code snippet below

```js
var playList = [
      ["Wild Ones", "Flo Rida"],
      ["Wings", "Birdi"],
      ["Pure Love", "White Lion"],
      ["Hold my hands", "Jess Glynn"]
    ];

var listSongs = "</ol>";
 function print(msg)
{
  document.write("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
}

function printSongs( songs )
{
  for(var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++)
    {
      listSongs += "<li>" + songs[i][0] + " " + ", by " + songs[i][1] + "</li>";
    }
  
  listSongs += "</ol>";
  print(listSongs);
}

var box = document.getElementById("container");

document.onLoad(box.innerHTML = printSongs(playList));
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
  </div>
```

Why before songs list undefined is being printed. Please help

Comment: Shouldn't "listSongs" being a <ol>? (Open tag and not close tag).

Comment: @Mr.Web print and printSongs are different functions. Also es6 gives us tail call elimination

Comment: [`print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) doesn't do what you're thinking

Comment: @GeorgeSimms sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `printSongs` function doesn't return any specific value. If you don't specify a return value, the function will return the value `undefined`.

As you are running the code from the `load` event (or at least try to), you shouldn't use `document.write`. Once the page is loaded, using `document.write` will implicitly call `window.open` so that a new page is created which will replace the current page.

Return the HTML code from the function instead of writing it out:

```js
var playList = [
  ["Wild Ones", "Flo Rida"],
  ["Wings", "Birdi"],
  ["Pure Love", "White Lion"],
  ["Hold my hands", "Jess Glynn"]
];

function print(msg) {
  return "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
}

function printSongs(songs) {
  var listSongs = "<ol>"; // should be starting tag, not an ending tag
  for(var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    listSongs += "<li>" + songs[i][0] + " " + ", by " + songs[i][1] + "</li>";
  }
  listSongs += "</ol>";
  return print(listSongs);
}

// The property is named onload, not onLoad, and it's in the window object
// It's not a function, you assign a function to it
window.onload = function() {
  // get the element inside the load event handler
  var box = document.getElementById("container");
  box.innerHTML = printSongs(playList);
};
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

print and print songs don't actually return anything, so they return undefined.

Change

```
 document.write(...stuff...);
```

To

```
 return ...stuff...;
```

And

```
print(listSongs);
```

To

```
return print(listSongs);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few problems I think:

- When first initialising `listSongs`, you need to set it to an opening tag of `<ol>` rather than the closing one. So it should become: `listSongs = <ol>;`.
- The major problem was the `document.write` inside your `print` function. You probably don't need that because you already are expecting to set `box` element's `innerHTML` to be filled by whatever `printSongs` can return.
- So include a `return` statement in your `printSongs` to return all the `listSongs` after the loop is done.

***Snippet:***

```js
var playList = [
  ["Wild Ones", "Flo Rida"],
  ["Wings", "Birdi"],
  ["Pure Love", "White Lion"],
  ["Hold my hands", "Jess Glynn"]
];

var listSongs = "<ol>";

function printSongs(songs) {
  for (var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    listSongs += "<li>" + songs[i][0] + " " + ", by " + songs[i][1] + "</li>";
  }

  listSongs += "</ol>";
  return listSongs;
}

var box = document.getElementById("container");
box.innerHTML = printSongs(playList)
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

I should also add that wrapping an `ol` within a `p` element won't work because [`p` element only allows `inline` HTML elements within it and `ol` is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5681796/3344111).