# Python lxml's XPath not finding <ul> in <p> tags

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have a problem with the XPath function of pythons lxml. A minimal example is the following python code:

```
from lxml import html, etree

text = """
      <p class="goal">
            <strong>Goal</strong> <br />
            <ul><li>test</li></ul>
        </p>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(text)
thesis_goal = tree.xpath('//p[@class="goal"]')[0]
print etree.tostring(thesis_goal)
```

Running the code produces

```
<p class="goal">
            <strong>Goal</strong> <br/>
            </p>
```

As you can see, the entire `<ul>` block is lost. This also means that it is not possible to address the `<ul>` with an XPath along the lines of `//p[@class="goal"]/ul`, as the `<ul>` is not counted as a child of the `<p>`.

Is this a bug or a feature of lxml, and if it is the latter, how can I get access to the entire contents of the `<p>`? The thing is embedded in a larger website, and it is not guaranteed that there will even *be* a `<ul>` tag (there may be another `<p>` inside, or anything else, for that matter).

**Update**: Updated title after answer was received to make finding this question easier for people with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ul` elements (or more generally [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1)) are [not allowed inside `p` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5681481/190597) (which can only contain [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1)). Therefore `lxml.html` parses `text` as

```
In [45]: print(html.tostring(tree))
<div><p class="goal">
            <strong>Goal</strong> <br>
            </p><ul><li>test</li></ul>

</div>
```

The `ul` follows the `p` element. So you could find the `ul` element using the XPath

```
In [47]: print(html.tostring(tree.xpath('//p[@class="goal"]/following::ul')[0]))
<ul><li>test</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

@unutbu has correct anwser. Your HTML is not valid and html parser will produce unexpected results. As it's said in the lxml docs,

> The support for parsing broken HTML depends entirely on libxml2's
>   recovery algorithm. It is not the fault of lxml if you find documents
>   that are so heavily broken that the parser cannot handle them. There
>   is also no guarantee that the resulting tree will contain all data
>   from the original document. The parser may have to drop seriously
>   broken parts when struggling to keep parsing. Especially misplaced
>   meta tags can suffer from this, which may lead to encoding problems.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can fallback to xml parser

```
# Changing html to etree here will produce behaviour you expect
tree = etree.fromstring(text)
```

or move to more advanced website parsing package such as BeautifulSoup4, for example