# Is Angular incapable of handling <p> tags?

Tags: angular

When I add `<p>` tags to a component template Angular 6 silently fails. No error is displayed on the CLI but the page renders blank.

Luckily Chrome displays an error in the console: `Unexpected closing tag "p". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.`

Here's the template with `<p>` tags:

```
<div id="SideNavMenu" class="sideNav">
  <p>
    <span id="CategoryListCaret">&#9658;</span>
    <a href="#" id="CategoryListHeader" class="sideNav__header sideNav__header--closed">Categories</a>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let itemtype of itemtypes">
        {{ itemtype.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span id="TopicListCaret">&#9658;</span>
    <a href="#" id="TopicListHeader" class="sideNav__header sideNav__header--closed">Topics</a>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let keyword of keywords">
            {{ keyword.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```

If I remove both sets of `<p>` tags it renders with no errors. So are `<p>` tags incompatible with Angular now? Or is something else going on?

Comment: Are you allowed to put `ul` inside a `p` element in HTML 5?

Comment: It is not a bug @Igor is correct here. But i agree that the error should be more descriptive

Comment: nope you are not allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5681796/8493981

Comment: Huh. Today I learned... Only these elements are allowed in p tags  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content

Comment: @Igor I'm curious why when I was prototyping this statically Chrome issued no complaints, but when it's put into an Angular component everything falls apart?

Comment: @Legion - many browsers don't "complain" about invalid HTML, they are pretty lax and try to do the best they can rendering it. The `angular` framework probably has a more stringent check built into it. The latter is just a guess, you would have to dig into the inner workings of the template engine to know for sure.

Answer (score -1):

According to the MDN docs for the p tag:

> The end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed
>   by an  element, or if there is no more content in the parent
>   element and the parent element is not an  element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p