# Errors in HTML - red ending paragraph tags

Tags: html, css

This is my first webpage, and the end paragraph tags are red.

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong, please?

This is my code. It was working fine, but when I have tried to add some CSS to it, it started displaying my text in a weird way, so I assume it must have some errors in my code.

```html
<body>

  <header>
    <h1><a href="http://epro.motorparks.co.uk/?" title="Engagement Pro">Engagement Pro</a></h1>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
    <h3>Below you will find answers to the questions we get asked the most about Engagement Pro.</h3>
    <div>

      <p>
        Managers
        <ul>
          <li>Why can't log in?</li>
          <li>A lead came through with no contact details, how do I remove it?</li>
          <li>I have added a comment to an unlogged lead, why is it not excluded?</li>
          <li>A guest enquired twice, but when I created the enquiry it didn't link to the other one.</li>
          <li>Where do I find leads that are being added in my diary by reception?</li>
        </ul>
      </p>

      <p>
        Sales associates
        <ul>
          <li>Why can't log in?</li>
          <li>Why doesn't the 'Export to Pinnacle' button work?</li>
          <li>Why do I have guests I know nothing about in my diary?</li>
          <li>Is there an easier way to see my diary for today, other han changing the date range?</li>
          <li>When adding an appointment, it doesn't show in my appointments diary</li>
          <li>Why are the postcodes highlighted yellow or green sometimes?</li>
        </ul </p>

        <p>
          Product geniuses
          <ul>
            <li>Why can't log in?</li>
            <li>Why does my video have so little views?</li>
            <li>Why can I not save a video?</li>
          </ul>
        </p>

        <p>For any other questions/suggestions please contact Steven Harris or Andreea Mitel.</p>

  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: check by closing your tags, you can use validator to check your hrml code on errors: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: You must not put list within a paragraph. <ul> is not allowed within <p>

Comment: What do you mean "in red"? Without CSS there's no reason for anything to be red...

Answer (score 2):

You must note that `<ul>` is not allowed within a `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I found some code error in your code and fixed them with HTML comment. Hope now it will work fine for you! :)

Here one thing to remember that: `ul` elements are not legally allowed inside `p` elements. [Here is the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside?answertab=oldest#tab-top). In your code you also forget to close some tags/some end tags are missing.

```html
<body>

  <header>
    <h1><a href="http://epro.motorparks.co.uk/?" title="Engagement Pro">Engagement Pro</a></h1>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
    <h3>Below you will find answers to the questions we get asked the most about Engagement Pro.</h3>
    <div>

      <p>Managers</p>
      <!-- Properly closing <p> -->
      <ul>
        <li>Why can't log in?</li>
        <li>A lead came through with no contact details, how do I remove it?</li>
        <li>I have added a comment to an unlogged lead, why is it not excluded?</li>
        <li>A guest enquired twice, but when I created the enquiry it didn't link to the other one.</li>
        <li>Where do I find leads that are being added in my diary by reception?</li>
      </ul>


      <p>Sales associates</p>
      <!-- Properly closing <p> -->
      <ul>
        <li>Why can't log in?</li>
        <li>Why doesn't the 'Export to Pinnacle' button work?</li>
        <li>Why do I have guests I know nothing about in my diary?</li>
        <li>Is there an easier way to see my diary for today, other han changing the date range?</li>
        <li>When adding an appointment, it doesn't show in my appointments diary</li>
        <li>Why are the postcodes highlighted yellow or green sometimes?</li>
      </ul>
      <!-- <ul> was not properly closed -->

      <p>Product geniuses</p>
      <!-- Properly closing <p> -->
      <ul>
        <li>Why can't log in?</li>
        <li>Why does my video have so little views?</li>
        <li>Why can I not save a video?</li>
      </ul>

      <p>For any other questions/suggestions please contact Steven Harris or Andreea Mitel.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Closing <div> was missing -->
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```