# How to align one list element right while keeping the rest centered?

Tags: html, css

I have a centered footer on a website with navigational links, and a copyright notice. I would like to keep the copyright notice on the same line as the navigational links.

HTML:

```
    <div id="footer">
    <p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety.html">Safety</a></li>
        <li><a href="privacy-policy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="copyright">&copy; 2020 Company LLC</li>
    </ul>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
copyright {
    float: right;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

With this code, navigation links and copyright appear on the same line. However, the copyright is not positioned right and it appears scrunched. A thin white line appears to the bottom of the footer, which should not be there either. The three buttons at the top are center aligned for reference.

[image]

I would like to align the copyright on the right of the footer and center align the navigation links to the webpage. What am I missing here?

Comment: You shouldn't have `<li>`, `<ul>` inside `<p>` tags - [It's against spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside)

Comment: Good to know, thanks. That fixed the thin white bar underneath my footer.

Comment: your `copyright` selector don'st match anything. To match `class="copyright"` use `.copyright` selector