# Removing a line break after using list in paragraph

Tags: html, css

I am working on website where i have to put information so I am using a list inside a paragraph but after the list name the text moves to another line. I want to start a paragraph after the list.I have attached the output and my target.The output [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO0id.png) The target [Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9RPw.png)

```
    <div class="history">
        <h1 class="h-history">History</h1>
        <p class="p">It was established in 1879....</p>
        <h1 class="h-history">Areas and attractions</h1>
        <p class="p"><li>Elephant House</li>is the first....</p>

    </div>
```

Comment: Firstly, `li` elements should not be outside of an `ul` element, and `ul` element should not me wrapped on a `p` element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside

Comment: Do you have for each item of the list, a text like this to follow the list item ? How many items has your list ? Please give more code.

Comment: @robinvrd so tell me if i dont do it and i only define a list and after  that a paragraph it goes on next line,how can i start a paragraph after the list

Comment: you simply need to wrap your paragraph inside your list item `li`.

Comment: can you tell how to change bullet colors,when i did it did change color but the list name went to next line

Comment: @MikePopins you can change `bullet color` to define color on `li` and also inside `li` element define `color` which you want.

Answer (score 0):

`<li>` is not a list. It is a list item. By default, the list item is rendered as a block element and hence the following text will be shown below that block.

However, you can achieve your target like this:

```html
<div class="history">
    <h1>History</h1>
    <p>It was established in 1879....</p>
    <h1>Areas and attractions</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><b>Elephant house</b> is the most famous exhibit in the zoo.</li>
        <li><b>Ape house</b> be carefull! Some inhabitants might throw smelly stuff at you</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Here, `<ul>` (which is for unordered list) is used to markup a list. The list has 2 list items. A portion of the text content of the list items is emphasized as bold text (`<b>`).

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve by `:before` `content: '\2022';` property like below snippet.

```css
.bullet {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.bullet:before {
  content: '\2022';
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="history">
  <h1 class="h-history">History</h1>
  <p class="p">It was established in 1879.</p>
  <h1 class="h-history">Areas and attractions</h1>
  <p class="p bullet"><strong>Elephant House</strong>is the most famous exhibit in the zoo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```