# combining selectors in css

Tags: html, css

[image]

I was requesting some help in combinators (combining selectors). I'm looking to use the same font in a paragraph element that has a list element in it. I have tried the child combinator `>)` and the next sibling combinator `+` still nothing.

I was expecting by using the child combinator `>` it will work since the list element is a child of the paragraph element and using the next sibling selector `+` too because it is.

Comment: Hi. The `+` selector is the `adjacent selector`. Only the next adjacent element. Here more: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048t#toc-qa4w-x-y .  For the `>` selector I am -- not -- sure, if it only works for the `ul` in your case.

Comment: dint work, the > selector i mean

Comment: Do you have a `ul` or `ol`? 

Comment: We aren't going to be able to give a sensible answer without seeing the relevant code. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: imagine am usin a ul though i see its working when i use the + combinator  but only changing the li items and leaving the p

Comment: And it sounds as though you may have illegal HTML structures - have you put your code through a validator?e.g. https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: The `>` selector does -- not -- work, because a list inside a paragraph is -- not -- allowed. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5681796/2569323 .

Comment: For a parent selector see @frunkad answer. 

Comment: kindly check the question i have added a picture of the code

Comment: Welcome! Looking at the code in your screenshot, your HTML is invalid and needs to be rewritten entirely. Please post your relevant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new [:has child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) like

```css
p :has(ol)
```

Comment: i think this is for pseudo class elements or?

Comment: @victor :has doesn't necessarily have to be checking a pseudo element, however, I don't at all see the relevance of using it for your problem.

Comment: @AHaworth **Am looking to use the same font in a paragraph element that has a list element in it.** This points at this answer.

Comment: @deEr. The problem is that the HTML is not valid. While `:has()` may solve this particular issue, the code should be rewritten and most likely this answer **shouldn't** solve the OPs problem.

Comment: @disinfor Ah, I can see clearly now. The `p` automatically closes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listclassname p {
  ### your styles here
  ### etc etc etc
}
```